# File.ReadAllBytes() Out of memory exception

Tags: c#

I have small app that among other read any file (i.e. .exe, . jpg, . img and all others), transfer it to `bytes[]` trough `File.ReadAllBytes()`, encrypt it with 3DES and save with `File.WriteAllBytes()`. Than there is decrypt method that doing the same reverse. My problem is, everything is working fine up to 300MB original file, than I have out of memory exception. Any suggestion how to solve this problem? How to work with files >1GB? Can it help rather use streamreader or cryptostream reader and writer?

Reading and encrypting file:

```
 try
 {
     saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
     DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
     if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
     {
         byte[] Results;
         System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
         fileToEncrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
         byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text));
         TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
         TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
         TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
         TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
         Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(fileToEncrypt, 0, fileToEncrypt.Length);
         saveFileDialog1.FileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
         saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
         if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
         {
             File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Results);
         }
         TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
         HashProvider.Clear();
     }
 }
 catch
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Your system has not enough memory.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

Decrypting and saving:

```
 try
 {
     openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
     DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
     if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
     {
         byte[] Results;
         System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
         fileToDecrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
         byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text));
         TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
         TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
         TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
         TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
         Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(fileToDecrypt, 0, fileToDecrypt.Length);
         saveFileDialog1.FileName = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
         if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
         {
             File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Results);
         }
         TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
         HashProvider.Clear();
     }
 }
 catch 
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Master password is wrong", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

I am only hobby coder, so I pray for some benevolence with my code :)

`textbox1.Text` is master password.

Comment: Dont read the file into memory, just pass the `FileStream` to the encryption method

Comment: The mental mistake here is that you assume that the cryptography provider is also a stream.  It isn't, it is just an algorithm that transforms bytes.  You didn't use the CrytoStream class.  Just follow the MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: Looks like you are catching ALL exception. How could you be sure that it is an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: Thanks for answers: 1.Filestream is working up to 1GB what is improvement and limit is most likely only system (4GB RAM and win7).  2.I am not assume I am using cryptostream, I am asking if use cryptostream can solve problem:)                                         3.I am catching all exceptions but when I am not I have classic Out of memory exception window. App is very small and without errors(really:)                                                   Anyway I will post Filestream solution soon, I must only finish decrypt method.

Comment: @Poool777 There is no size restrictions on `FileStream`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have something using cryptostream - on my notebook 8 min to encrypt 2,7GB file.
Thanks Magnus for effort, I will try your code also

encrypt method

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            FileStream readFile = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream writeFile = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            writeFile.SetLength(0);

            byte[] storage = new byte[100];
            long fileWritten = 0;
            long totlen = readFile.Length;
            int bytesToWrite;

            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TDES.Key = TDESKey;
            TDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(writeFile, TDES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            while (fileWritten < totlen)
            {
                bytesToWrite = readFile.Read(storage, 0, 100);
                cryptStream.Write(storage, 0, bytesToWrite);
                fileWritten = fileWritten + bytesToWrite;

            }

            cryptStream.Close();
            TDES.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }
```

Decrypt method is the same using  `TDES.CreateDecryptor()` instead  `TDES.CreateEncryptor()`.
I must say `File.ReadAllBytes()` and`File.WriteAllBytes()` are much faster with file 300MB size than stream.

Comment: A buffer of size 100 is way to small, increase it to gain performance. At least 4096.